# Google Sheets - Find row at least one year before last row

Tags: date, google-sheets, formula

I have some data that looks basically like this:

```
╔════╦════════════╦═══════╗
║    ║     A      ║   B   ║
╠════╬════════════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ 2013-09-19 ║ 43902 ║
║  2 ║ 2013-09-26 ║ 44129 ║
║  3 ║ 2013-10-15 ║ 44326 ║
║  4 ║ 2014-04-13 ║ 44557 ║
║  5 ║ 2014-05-05 ║ 44779 ║
║ 23 ║ 2014-10-09 ║ 50264 ║
║ 24 ║ 2014-10-23 ║ 50511 ║
║ 25 ║ 2014-11-15 ║ 50746 ║
╚════╩════════════╩═══════╝
```

What I want to do is look at the last line (25) and find the first line above it that is at least a year older (line 3) and return B25-B3. I was hoping there would be a series of formula I could piece together, but the hardest part is finding the row with the proper date.
Do I need a custom script?

Comment: Does this help: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zlyokmY82CbMuyHSkRPUxEpdZJWo1xuLDrYbYH0RwJU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @paul This is on the right track, but I need to know which row is the last one to have the '0' in your spreadsheet. FYI if you want to include an entire column you can use B:B rather than B$1:B$500

Comment: I thought you would only be interested in the cells with a '1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes the dates are in ascending order, that the date must occur at least 365 days before the last date (ie doesn't take into account leap years), and every date is unique. However, all of these assumptions could be worked around.

`=LOOKUP(1E+308,B:B)-VLOOKUP(MAX(A:A)-365,A:B,2)`

If there are no dates at least 365 days before, the formula will return #N/A.

Comment: This is exactly the trick I needed, the finished result looks like this:
=max(sheet2!B:B)-VLOOKUP(max(sheet2!A:A)-365, sheet2!A:B, 2)
And yes, it probably can break in a number of ways, but since I'm the only one using this sheet I can handle that, if ever I was doing this for a user, I'd find a way to put in some error checking. Thanks.